Can one have a Christmas tree in their sukkah?
There's a Jewish teenage boy who isn't so into his Orthodoxy. He said to his father: "I want you to have  a Christmas tree in the sukkah this year, etc, and I will come in with my friends into the sukkah." Maybe they want to be different, etc. Is there any Jewish violation in having a Christmas tree with or without lights on it in the sukkah during Sukkos?

You forgot to include the part of the story where the teenager goes to his friends, who are waiting outside, snickering, and saying to them "You guys owe me $50, I got my parents to put a xmas tree in their sukkah, like I said I would. For $100 I'll get them to sing carols"

Your question is stated in a form which is not appropriate for this site. You are repeating a well-known bad joke about Jewish people. If you are interested in a question about a christmas tree in a succah you do not need the story about a teenage Jewish boy.

Is this meant to be a joke?

As a rule, Mitzvos don't cancel each other - one can eat Matzah on Passover with ham.

I think you need to ask a Rabbi who knows the family and situation.
It is likely idolatry:
Yirmiyahu 10:2-4

So says the Lord: of the way of the nations you shall not learn, and
from the signs of the heaven be not dismayed, for the nations are
dismayed from them.
3For the statutes of the peoples are vanity, for it is but a stock
that one cut from the forest, the handiwork of a carpenter with a
small axe.
4With silver and gold he beautifies it, with nails and with sledge
hammers they strengthen them so that it does not bend.

I have heard of those who belong to that religion and do everything on x-mas not even do it...
But like I said maybe speaking to an Orthodox Rabbi who understand all the ins and outs can better advise the situation. There might be some sort of compromise or something that can be had.
What if the Schach (ie: roof) is pine leaves and there are xmas lights on the roof? Someone competent who knows more would be likely much more helpful.
Side note: It is interesting it mentions this in association with a carpenter...

According to the wikipedia article, the origin of Christmas trees may not be pagan, as the custom originated among the protestants in Germany and Livonia (current Latvia and Estonia) around 1600s, even though there were some similar pagan variants of it in the past. The triangular shape of the tree is understood as symbolic of the Christian trinity. As pointed out by R. Kravitz, while certain beliefs about G-d may be permissible for non-Jews, the Christian theology concerning G-d is one example of a belief that is absolutely forbidden to Jews according to the Hebrew Bible. Usage of symbolism associated with forbidden beliefs cannot take place in a succah at all.
